# Nice way of accessing member variables based on a switch

Tags: c++, coding-style, readability

I'm working on code that contains several functions with the following pattern

```
memberType* var = NULL;
switch(someVariable)
{
  case 0: var = &object.MemberVariable1; break;
  case 1: var = &object.MemberVariable2; break;
  case 2: var = &object.MemberVariable3; break;
}
```

The member variables are of the same type. In some switches there are several dozen cases, which clutter up the function body with what's basically just data. I'd like to create an array, map or something similar so I could access the members based on the input value.

I'm thinking of having something like

```
sometype array[size] = {member1, member2, member3}
```

so the function could contain

```
memberType* var = array[index];
```

instead of the switch.

**1.**
My first thought was creating a union in the class that contains the individual member variables and an array, so I can access either the individual members or access them via array + index. This is ugly, not apparent from the code at first glance and forces the member vars to be declared in a consecutive manner. It also does not allow me to access the same member variable for different indices.

**2.**
Having an array that contains function pointers to functions that return individual member variables forces me to create tons of one line getter functions.

**3.**
Having a statically allocated object so I can do something like

```
int offsets[size] = {
*(int*)&staticObject.member1 - *(int*)&staticObject,
*(int*)&staticObject.member2 - *(int*)&staticObject, 
*(int*)&staticObject.member3 - *(int*)&staticObject}
```

and use it

```
var = (memberType*)(*(int*)&object + offsets[index]);
```

is terrible.

Is there a nice way to get rid of this unnecessarily verbose pattern?

Disclaimer: I did not test the code used in the examples. It's just for illustration.

---

**Edit:** One important thing I forgot to mention: I don't want to change the size of the class because of serialization - I have yet to understand the implementation I'm working with.

Comment: There are plenty of map implementations in C out there.  Why not just use one of those?

Comment: The question is how to store accesses to member variables, not the container type or implementation

Comment: Why aren't the members in an array to begin with?  That is, why do you have discrete members when you seem to really want an array?

Comment: @JoeZ: Because every variable has a different meaning and is used differently in the remainder of the code. The array would make sense only the functions with these switches. It's old code I'm refactoring so I have to be careful.

Comment: You can create a const&[N], or use an GetMemberAt(int) that can do bound checking (same as probably does your switch). The At is probably the better one.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://ideone.com/d5UPPR) do?

Comment: What's really the problem here?

Comment: @Silvester Seredi: What you are trying to "invent" here with your offsets has already been invented. It is called *member pointers* (or *pointers to members*). It is accurately described in user2510575's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out [pointers to members](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr034.htm). This will allow you to implement your suggestion (3) more cleanly.

Lets say your class looks like this.

```
class X {
public:
  memberType MemberVariable1;
  memberType MemberVariable2;
  memberType MemberVariable3;
};
```

Now we'll define an array of pointers to member variables.

```
typedef memberType X::*MemberVar;
MemberVar ptrs[3] = {
  &X::MemberVariable1,
  &X::MemberVariable2,
  &X::MemberVariable3
};
```

Then you can use the array like this.

```
X obj;
memberType var = obj.*(ptrs[index]);
```

Comment: +1. This is precisely what the OP is trying to invent from scratch.

Comment: Awesome. First time I'm hearing about this, but it's exactly what I wanted. The semicolons in the array initialization should be changed to commas, though.

Answer (score 4):

Just [encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) the `switch`:

1. In the object's class, define `GetMemberVariableAt(int)` and move the switch in there.
2. Then, have your client code ask for `object.GetMemberVariableAt(someVariable)`.

If you do this, it won't be all that important that you're using a nasty switch to get to the right member variable, because the switch will be internal to your object's implementation, not smeared across your code. And, you have the piece of mind that you can improve it later with minimal effort, switching to an array or whatever your mind (or your performance requirements, perhaps) desires.

If you don't control the source code of the class of your object, you can still proxy it or put an adapter in front of it, and code to the proxy or adapter.

---

The solution I am giving here is intended to make it easier to choose between the alternatives that you already offer in your question, by reducing the importance of the  ugliness factor.

I should add that between the `switch` and an array of member references solution, I prefer the `switch`, because data duplication can be a wealthy source of latent bugs and complicated code. If you can *replace* the member variables with an array internally, I would go for that over the `switch`, but if you have to maintain both an array and the fields outside `GetMemberVariableAt`, this is data duplication that I would warmly recommend against.

Comment: My goal is to be able to declare the return value associated with the input value separately in a less error prone style. Extracting the switch to a separate function does not make the switch itself more readable.

Comment: Understood. I don't know that there is a style that would win over the others in my mind. You yourself present a number of alternatives, but are concerned about how ugly they are. I offer a solution that makes the ugliness of the solution less important, giving you code clarity while allowing you to think about performance and other details. I would add, with regard to the alternatives that you presented, that I prefer solutions that do not require data redundancy, i.e. putting your values in both an array and instance fields. So if you don't like the switch, replace the fields with an array.

Comment: To continue and build on my last comment, I prefer the `switch` to a hybrid field+array solution, because data redundancy runs you the risk of latent bugs, while the switch does less of that at the cost of some verbosity. The array solution also pays a price: your code may become more subtle, and readability is a chief concern in code. If the fields can be naturally thought of as an array to the point that they feel more natural grouped together than as children of the class, then let the array go. Otherwise, I don't mind the `switch` that much. Readability + minimal latent bugs works for me.